# Possible to move embedded swf from one tag to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, swfobject

I have two containers for embedded swf files in my html:

```
<div id="player1"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
```

Let's say I load an embedded video into the first div tag (player1):

```
swfobject.embedSWF("someURL","player1");
```

Can I 'move' this embedded object to the player2 tag so I can load another video into the player1 tag? The key is that I don't want to reload/embed the video again. I just want to move the tag or somehow rename the tag ids (jquery?) or some other solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Did I solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<script>
function moveSwf() {
document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML= document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML= " ";
}
</script>

<div id="player1">
<object data="name1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="50" height="50">
<param name="movie" value="name1.swf">
</object>
</div>

<div id="player2">
<object data="name2.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="50" height="50">
<param name="movie" value="name2.swf">
</object>
</div>

<button onclick="moveSwf()">Click to move</button>
```